# Prove that $\sum_{s\in S}|f(s)|=\sup\Big\{\sum_{s\in R}|f(s)|\mid R\subseteq S $ is finite $\Big\}$

Tags: real-analysis

Given the following definitions:

$\sum_{s\in S} f(s)=\infty$ means For all $M\in\mathbb{R}$, there is a finite set $T\subseteq S$ such that, for all finite sets $T'\subseteq S$ that contain $T$ one has $\sum_{s\in T'} f(s)>M$

$\sum_{s\in S} f(s)=a$ means For all $\epsilon>0$, there is a finite set $T\subseteq S$ such that, for all finite sets $T'\subseteq S$ that contain $T$, one has $|a-\sum_{s\in T'} f(s)|<\epsilon$

Prove:  If $f:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $A=\sup\Big\{\sum_{s\in R}|f(s)|\mid R\subseteq S $ is finite $\Big\}$, prove that $\sum_{s\in S}|f(s)|=A$.

So here is my proof so far:

Let $f:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $A=\sup\Big\{\sum_{s\in R}|f(s)|\mid R\subseteq S $ is finite $\Big\}$.

First consider the case in which $A=\infty$. So $\sum_{s\in R}|f(s)|$ is not bounded above. So there exists $M\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\sum_{s\in R}|f(s)|>M$ for all finite $R\subseteq S$. Thus by definition $\sum_{s\in S} |f(s)|=\infty = \sup\Big\{\sum_{s\in R}|f(s)|\mid R\subseteq S $ is finite $\Big\}=A$.

Now consider the case in which $A\in\mathbb{R}$. So $\sum_{s\in R}|f(s)|\le A$ for all finite $R\subseteq S$. Let $T\subseteq R$. Then $\sum_{s\in T}|f(s)|\le A$. So $\sum_{s\in T}|f(s)|-A\le 0$.

Here is where I am stuck. I need to show that $|\sum_{s\in T}|f(s)|- A|<\epsilon$. I am not sure how to get there from where I am. Clearly if I have $|\sum_{s\in T}|f(s)|- A|\le 0$ then I can choose any $\epsilon>0$ and I'm done, but I can't just throw in the absolute value.

Comment: Quick observation:  you write that "$\sum_{s\in R}|f(s)|$ is not bounded above.  So there exists $M\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\sum_{s\in R}|f(s)|>M$ for all finite $R\subset S$."  This is wrong.  The correct statement would instead be "So for all $M\in \mathbb{R}$ there is some finite $R\subset S$ such that $\sum_{s\in R}|f(s)|>M$."  Next step is to note that all the $|f(s)|$ are nonnegative, so that if $R\subset R'$, then we also have $\sum_{s\in R'}|f(s)|>M$.  That matches the definition you gave of $\sum_{s\in S} f(s)=\infty$.

Comment: That makes absolute sense, now I'm not even sure what I was thinking before. Thank you. So then I can use similar reasoning in the case $A\in\mathbb{R}$ in that for finite $R'\supset R$, $A\ge\sum_{R'}|f(s)|>\sum_{R}|f(s)|$